# How do I check if my array contains my guessed numbers respectively?

Tags: c#, arrays

If my array contains random numbers in respective order (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and I want to create another array of my guesses (1,4,2,4,5,6,7), I would like to see how many I got correct, respectively.

Here's my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Can you guess the numbers that have appeared on the screen respectively?");
        for (int i = 1; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ". ");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            userGuess[i] = Convert.ToInt32(temp);

        }

        for (int i = 1; i < num.Length; i++)
        {
            if (num[i] == userGuess[i])//Here's my problem. I am unable to 
                                       //test whether my guess resides in the num array.
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("You got " + count + " guesses right.");
```

Count should end up with 5 correct if I was to choose 1,4,2,4,5,6,7, judging that my num array contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Your array indices are different. In your first for loop, you start with index = 1, however in your second for loop, you start with index = 0. i.e. you aren't comparing the correct array positions

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point at "if(num[i] == userGuess[i])" and see what are the actual values being compared?

Comment: I've seen this used, but I've never learnt it myself. This would be helpful indeed, care to explain a little?

Comment: I think you go to the wrong direction. It' not about you start your num array that contains you "answer key" that you set with no input from user, but it's about how to dedicate your array by inputted answer from user. Please see my answer for more information.

Comment: If you add a break point, the code execution will pause when it encounters the breakpoint. You can then put your mouse over some of the variables names and a little popup will show what the current value is. You can do a google search for "visual studio breakpoint" if you want more information about breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @failedprogramming said, you missmatch index between array userGuess and num.
I know you want to start user input with no."1" but, it will get your userguess array will be moving in wrong index.

```
1     2    3    4    5    6    7
blank 1    4    2    4    5    6
```

So, you have no right answer.

Maybe you can use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Can you guess the numbers that have appeared on the screen respectively?");
            for (int i = 1; i < num.Length+1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + ". ");
                string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                userGuess[i-1] = Convert.ToInt32(temp);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            {
                if (num[i] == userGuess[i])//Here's my problem. I am unable to 
                //test whether my guess resides in the num array.
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("You got " + count + " guesses right.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the two arrays are of equal length, you can use LINQ's [`Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
var result = num.Zip(userGuess, (n, u) => n == u ? 1 : 0).Sum();
```

This compares each corresponding element in the two lists, returning 1 for a match or 0 for a non-match, then adds up the values. The result is effectively the number of matches.